# Qt and serial port programming

Tags: c++, qt, qtserialport

Is there any serial port facilities in Qt ?

If not, which crossplatform (desirable) libraries (for working with serial port and, maybe, with other I/O ports), do you recommend ?

Comment: QtSerialPort is included in Qt 5.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the Project [QextSerialPort](http://qextserialport.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I'm using this at the moment and it works great!  Saved me tons of time.

Comment: I think the recommended solution is better to be QtSerialPort these days.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there's always [Boost](http://boost.org).

In Boost there is a great Async I/O library called [ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). It can perform operations in all sorts of endpoints, including [serial ports](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html).

There is a great [example](http://www.nabble.com/Simple-serial-port-demonstration-with-boost-asio-asynchronous-I-O-p19849520.html) about how to build a minicom-like application using Boost::Asio, that you can use to see if ASIO will attend your needs.

Since boost works on all platforms/compilers under the sun, the cross platform requirement can be checked.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Qt serial library, works on Win, WinCE, Linux (i386 and ARM), Mac...

http://gitorious.org/inbiza-labs/qserialport

Also, it is based on QIODevice for a native feel, with it you can, if you like, direct serial communication onto TCPIP with little no no effort.

It is LGPL also... enjoy.

Comment: Qt Serial Library is LGPL: https://gitorious.org/inbiza-labs/qserialport/blobs/master/COPYING