# How to retrieve a data from a directory by sending a request through the serial port?

Tags: c++, c, serial-port

I have a controller which has a serial port and ethernet. I want to retrieve an event and the data associated with this event from the event directory through the serial or ethernet port of the controller. I do have a packet format (request packet data) for the specified event to be retrieved. Can anyone tell me how to retrieve the data by sending a request through the serial port? I am beginner and not that much well-versed in programming.

Comment: You are likely to get no answer because your answer is to general, to less details and kind of "how do I program the project". A direction is: decide which connection you want (or ask this) and research how to implement it on the target and the host. My choice would be to use the serial (RS232) as it is easier to implement.

Comment: The serial port at the controller is already interfaced and I need to send a request and get an automatic reply from the controller. I should initiate a program at the host port that sends a request and gets back a reply. How should I implement it with the serial port?

Comment: Question is incredibly open ended.  try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459344/qt-and-serial-port-programming

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have some kind of a program running on your embedded platform, listening to the serial port and answering requests.  This kind of program is usually called a "daemon" (pronounced the same as "demon"; just like "Caesar" rhymes with "sea star").

If you already have a daemon, you will need to figure out what format it uses.  Since I have no idea what you might have I cannot even guess.

If you will be writing your own daemon, you will need to choose some sort of protocol.  Personally I like the JSON format for a serial protocol; it is simple enough that you can extract data just using `sscanf()` from the C library if there is not a better library available, and of course it's easy to build JSON strings just using `sprintf()`.

http://json.org/

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the **[Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.easysw.com/~mike/serial/serial.html)**. If you are bound to Windows for some reason, you get POSIX through installing Cygwin. Expect to become familiar with man pages like `termios` and `fcntl` since you'll first have to set the serial port parameters to work with your device, though they're likely to be the standard 8-N-1 at some rate. Then it's a matter of reading and writing bytes to the port's file descriptor. You're more likely to be using the low level `open()`, `close()`, `read()`, and `write()`, which are a level below the `stdio` (`printf`, `fopen`, `stdout`) you're more likely to be used to as a newer programmer.

Computers these days often lack the RS232 serial port, so if you need one you can find a cheap USB adapter. Be aware that USB adapters don't necessarily implement some of the ancillary signals (RTS,CTS,etc.) in my experience.

Also look into libraries for your specific needs and situation.

You should specify the controller for more useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should support any data exchange protocol. You can find this info in documenttion. May be, it supports MODBUS or MODBUS TCP. In this case you can use any modbus compatible software.